# $(X,Y)$ is distributed uniformly over the square with vertices $(1,1)(1,-1)(-1,1)(-1,-1)$. Compute $\mathbb{P}(|X+Y|<1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$(X,Y)$ is distributed uniformly over the square with vertices $(1,1)(1,-1)(-1,1)(-1,-1)$. Compute $\mathbb{P}(|X+Y|<1)$

My attempt:$$\mathbb{P}(|X+Y|<1)=\int^1_{-1}\int^{1-y}_{-1-y}\frac{1}{4}dxdy=1$$

But the result is wrong obviously, I don't know why, does anyone could help me? Thanks!

Comment: Did you draw?...

Comment: Yes, so the answer should be $\frac{3}{4}$, but I'm wondering if I could do it in a formula way.

Comment: If you did draw a picture, you can see on it why the bounds in your double integral are wrong.

Comment: I got it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you draw a picture you see that the space $|X-Y|<1$ is a connection of the 4 points $(0,\pm1),(\pm1,0)$. Then by symmetry considerations it is sufficient to calculate the area in the positive quadrant relative to the area of the unit square on the positive quadrant. This area should be $1/2$ if my eyes and picture are correct. This area is written as an integral

$\int_0^1\int_0^{1-y}dxdy = 1/2.$